# Apple script error Finder got an error: AppleEvent handler failed

Tags: applescript

This is the script i am trying to make
i am trying to make a script to see if Fido_Data exsists on my desktop with a if and else statement but for some reason it just gets the error Finder got an error: AppleEvent handler failed.

```
tell application "Finder"
    if exists folder [homePath & "Desktop/Fido_Data"] then
        set FidoFolderExists to "yes"
    else
        display dialog homePath & "Desktop/"
        make new folder at [homePath & "Desktop/"] with properties {name:"Fido_Data"}
    end if
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
tell application "Finder"
    if exists folder ((path to desktop as text) & "Fido_Data") then
        set FidoFolderExists to "yes"
    else
        display dialog (path to desktop as text)
        make new folder at (path to desktop) with properties {name:"Fido_Data"}
    end if
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

I got stumbled across intermittent cases of finder getting file existence wrong in 10.10.5.  I suggest:

```
-- ------------------------------------------------------  
(*
  Philip Regan
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469389/applescript-testing-for-file-existence
*)
on fileExists(theFile) -- (String) as Boolean
    tell application "System Events"
        if exists file theFile then
            return true
        else
            return false
        end if
    end tell
end fileExists
```