# file exists is not working in applescript

Tags: file, applescript, exists

Im trying to detect if a file exists. However, the script stops and errors out instead of going to the "else" statement.

Any idea how to make this work?

```
tell application "Finder" 

    if exists file h then 

        display dialog "file exists"

    else

        display dialog "file doesnt exist"

    end if

end tell
```

Cheers

Ke

Comment: you should show the code of your script, or at least as much as it takes to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: ok, I have done, its pretty straight forward question though. Not sure why a script is required...

Comment: Its not a duplicate within the context of my code. I have already read that and it does not answer my question

Comment: @Paul R - Also notice that there is no accepted answer of the post you have given

Comment: Hey, Ke., Can you set the variable h in your example code?

Comment: @Ke.: see answer below - the subroutine from the top answer to the linked duplicate question seems to work as expected - maybe the problem lies elsewhere ?

Comment: If your code is erring then it is because of the variable "h". Your code is written such that "h" is a string. If h is not a string (a file reference, alias etc.) then your code will error. So you need to show what "h" is in your example. Or at least remove the word "file" from your if statement and try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a little example:

```
set h to (choose file with prompt "Pick a file…") as string

tell application "Finder"

    if exists file h then

        display dialog "file " & return & quoted form of h & return & " exists"

    else

        display dialog "file " & return & quoted form of h & return & " missing!"

    end if

end tell
```

Or without using `as string` which makes it even simpler:

```
set h to (choose file with prompt "Pick a file…")

tell application "Finder"

    if exists h then

        display dialog "file " & return & quoted form of (h as text) & return & " exists"

    else

        display dialog "file " & return & quoted form of (h as text) & return & " missing!"

    end if

end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [@PhilipRegan's subroutine from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3469708/253056), the following seems to work as expected:

```
set h to "/mach_kernel"
if FileExists(h) then
    display dialog (h & " exists!")
else
    display dialog (h & " does not exist")
end if

set h to "/foo"
if FileExists(h) then
    display dialog (" exists!")
else
    display dialog (h & " does not exist")
end if

on FileExists(theFile) -- (String) as Boolean
    tell application "System Events"
        if exists file theFile then
            return true
        else
            return false
        end if
    end tell
end FileExists
```

[image]

[image]